# Trying to SCP from Local Mac to Amazon AWS Linux Machine

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, mac, scp

I am trying to copy a file from my local Mac to my Linux instance running on the Amazon EC2 / AWS Cloud.

I am able to connect to the server via Terminal, but am unable to get my file up to the server.

Here is what I've tried:
(yes, I replaced myuser@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX with the actual server info)

> scp /Users/me/Desktop/file.txt myuser@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:file.txt
>
> result: Sink: scp: /Users/me/Desktop/file.txt: No such file or directory
>
> scp ~/Users/me/Desktop/file.txt myuser@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:file.txt
>
> result: scp: /home/myuser/Users/me/Desktop/file.txt: No such file or directory

So it seems that when I use the ~/Users/ ... it thinks I am trying to copy the file from the server? But when I only use /Users/ ... , it still says it cannot find the file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**More Info ...**

Here are some additional tries I have made, all with the same result:

> scp localhost:/Users/me/Desktop/file.txt myuser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/home/myuser/file.txt
>
> scp /Users/me/Desktop/file.txt myuser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/home/myuser/file.txt

Is there something else I need to do to tell it to grab the file from my desktop machine?

**Figured it out ...**

Okay, so I was trying to do this while I was already connected to the server. It makes sense to me now, but I was connecting to the server and then trying to move the file.

Thank you for all your help and sorry for the confusion !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you have to specify the path on the remote machine.

So...

```
scp /path/to/textfile.txt myuser@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:/path/to/where/you/want/it/
```

Comment: I have also tried that, makes no difference - and doesn't really answer the question of why it is saying it can't find the file on the local computer.

Comment: provide output of 'stat /path/to/file.txt'

Comment: If you're using the wrong syntax, you can get that error message - it's why I suggested it.

Comment: It says that it cannot stat the file... is there something I need to do to tell it to look on my local machine?

Comment: Please see edits to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

looks like your default directory on remote server is /Users/me/Desktop, you should create the directory on remote server,like this:

```
mkdir /Users/me/Desktop
```

or put the file.txt to a exiting path.

```
ssh /path/to/file.txt username@hostname.domain:/path/to/target/file.ext
```

Comment: No... /Users/me/Desktop is on my local machine.

Comment: Please see edits to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you gave defective path to command...

Most absolute path begins with slash `"/"` which means root directory. It's also applies to remote system. Check this out:

```
scp /path/to/read/file.txt username@hostname.domain:/file.txt
```

or

```
scp /path/to/read/file.txt username@hostname.domain:/path/to/write/file.txt
```

And also in your condition, you must check path if you get errors. You can check the path by type command below in your folder that where the `file.txt` is.

```
pwd
```

...
Anyway, if you think your file is on the right place, you can change directory to where it is and check the `pwd` result

if you can change your path by command below:

```
cd /Users/me/Desktop/
```

and you can list the file you want to send:

```
ls -la | grep file.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 me me 14320 2011-11-15 09:50 file.txt
```

there might be user permission issues.
Check if you can display inside the file by `cat file.txt`
If you do not have read permission on the file you can't send file to anywhere. First of all you must granted some permissions on that file.